# Authorize a client with his digital certificate from USB crypto tokens

Tags: asp.net, applet, public-key-encryption, digital-certificate

Basically we need to make sure the user is the right person ,even after username/password ,we need another round of verification by using **digital Certificate credentials**.
All clients will be having a **crypto usb with their private key**.

We need a scenario where the client user on concerned **Aspx** page should

- insert his Usb crypto token.
- select his certificate ,enter the usb pin (if any) .
- The server will authorize his action if he is the right person.

If it is possible,how ??.
Should I be making **Applet** for it,do I have to look for cryto usb hardware specific SDK.

Any reference ,would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, VKX. Did you manage to do this ? If yes, how ? If no, well...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080629/java-pkcs11-and-mskeystore
Which inturn invokes Crypto Key Softwares "Password Capture UI". Proper drivers should be installed and accessible from browser .

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, and you don't need to use an applet.  You can set your web service container (IIS, Tomcat, etc.) to enforce 2-way (mutual) SSL.

The client's certificate will be signed by a CA.  That CA's certificate must be in some type of a trust list that the server is pointing to.  The server will reject any client cert not signed by a CA in the trust list.

After the client cert's CA is found in the trust list, the cert will be forwarded to the web app, where further authorization can take place.

You shouldn't need "cryto usb hardware specific SDK" on the server side.  The server just receives it as a certificate.  The server doesn't know if it came from a file or a usb  token on the client side.  So the server just needs to know how to process X509 certificates.  The browser and/or the software drivers on the client side actually do all the interaction with the USB token, so that when the browser talks to the server, it is only sending a certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the authorization is required only at a specific page for a specific action,Not through the website.

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible. The applet can make the connection/verification with your crypto hardware and also communicate with your server (via direct communiction or jscript). If you go the applet route ensure the following:

1. (After implementing the actual logic (device communication etc))
2. Your applet must be digitally [signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html) with an official certificate (otherwise your users will get lots of warnings etc.)
3. the right permissions / [security settings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html) are set
4. Your device must be supported by java or offer an java API. It should support [JCA / JCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) or if it is a smartcard have a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/downloads/index.html), [here](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_3587361_3/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/).

Comment: My query is not regarding signing/deploying of applet,but authorizing a user having a private key in usb crypto token.

Comment: And that (as i wrote) is perfectly possible. The part about the applet signing/deploying was only mentioning of possible stumbling blocks on that way...