# Crypto Mate EVO with Java

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I have a Java app and I use many tokens in it but last week I received 30 tokens Crypto Mate EVO, this product: https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/494/cryptomate-evo-cryptographic-usb-tokens/

I can't use these tokens in Java. My working implementation starts like this:

```
PKCS11 p11 = PKCS11.getInstance(dllFileName, "C_GetFunctionList", null, false);
```

So for all working tokens, I found a DLL file at the producer that could be loaded using "PKCS11.getInstance" but for Crypto Mate EVO I found none. I actually tested all the DLLs in all the archives from the download section and the error is:

> java.io.IOException: The specified procedure could not be found.

So no DLL has the function C_GetFunctionLis. Does anyone have experience with this product in Java?

**UPDATE:**
Accessing the token using Windows-MY is not a problem. Like here: [Java - PKCS11 and MSKeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080629/java-pkcs11-and-mskeystore)

Answer (score 1):

The page targeted by your link has the following lines in tab `SDK` and section `Kit Features`:

```
ACS Middlewares comply with the following:
    PCKS #11
```

So somewhere must be DLL with this function.

Answer (score 1):

ACS answered me and redirected me to this page to download the necessary files: https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/495/evo-pki-kit-pki-software-solution/?fbclid=IwAR0gM5bQgTQX-cGHSz3uJ7k9D36q8RlF8cUtCUKcK7yihUlF3poP4FdsxOo

But the kit they recommended is not free. All previous PKCS11 providers I tested give these files for free, ACS is not.

Anyway, Crypto Mate EVO is working in Java with Windows store, the DLL's are optional now...